# Implementar Check All AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

Estoy intentado poner en una página que carga un listado de resultados, con un checkbox cada uno, mostrado con AngularJS, un checkbox que al hacer click, marque todos los checkbox del listado.
Para ello, he creado este checkbox así:

```
<input title="Marcar todos" id="sf_admin_list_batch_checkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll();" />
```

Luego recorro la variable que almacenará el Json que llega desde el action (var JsonData)

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" class="sf_admin_batch_checkbox">
```

Por último intento crear una función para que marque todos, pero no logro que funcione:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkAll()
{

$scope.data = {};

$scope.checkAll = function () {
    if ($scope.selectedAll) {
        $scope.selectedAll = true;
    } else {
        $scope.selectedAll = false;
    }
    angular.forEach($scope.Items, function (item) {
        item.Selected = $scope.selectedAll;
    });
}
}
</script>
```

El problema es que no sé que poner en el $scope.data

No sé si voy bien encaminado

Un saludo.
Gracias

Actualmente tengo el input

```
<input title="Marcar todos" id="sf_admin_list_batch_checkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll();" />
```

y un script que ha dejado de funcionar al modificar el input del bucle

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkAll()

{
  var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); for(var index = 0; index < boxes.length; index++) { box = boxes[index]; if (box.type == 'checkbox' && box.className == 'sf_admin_batch_checkbox') box.checked = document.getElementById('sf_admin_list_batch_checkbox').checked } return true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas! Puedes probar de esta forma?

En lugar de onclick vamos a utilizar `ng-change` para que se ejecute cuando el valor cambie.

**HTML**

```
<input title="Marcar todos" id="sf_admin_list_batch_checkbox" 
type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-change="checkAll();" />
```

Luego, vamos a recorrer nuestra colección y en función del valor de del primer check, vamos a activar o desactivar todos los checks.

**CONTROLLER**:

```
$scope.checkAll = function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function (item) {
        item.selected = $scope.selectedAll;
    });
}
```

Con respecto a tu `$scope.data`, debería ser la colección a recorrer.
¿Tu lista tendrá algo mas que los checkboxs?

Tu data podría ser perfectamente solo un array de objetos que tengan de valor el Selected

```
$scope.data = [{selected:false},{selected:false},{selected:false}]
```

De esta forma te saldrán 3 checks a false.

También puedes a tu colección de objetos añadirle un valor selected

```
$scope.data = [{id:1, nombre: 'pedro', selected:false},{id:2, nombre: 'luis', 
selected:false},{id:3, nombre: 'marcos', selected:false}]
```

Si tu colección viene como respuesta a una llamada al servidor, puedes enlazarlo perfectamente sin crear el campo selected, ya que como valor inicial, al no existir será false y cuando actives el check creará el atributo con el valor de true.

Te dejo un ejemplo en [codepen](https://codepen.io/naimad/pen/rGwWYy)

Comment: Lo que pones en "Controller", va dentro de <script>, verdad? Si es así, no funciona
Por otro lado, la lista tienen los checkbox para seleccionarlos y poderlos borrar todos de golpe, y un botón de eliminar y editar a la derecha de cada registro

Comment: Estas usando angularjs? Es que no veo en tu codigo algo que haga referencia a un controller... y con tu pregunta de ahora me has dejado un poco descolocado. Sin embargo, si que usar ng-repeat en tu codigo html.

Comment: Te he añadido un ejemplo para que veas la estructura completa

Comment: Pues ahora me haces dudar, pero el ng-repeat y todo eso es de Angular.
La página es un "partial" llamado _listAngular.php.
El bucle y todo eso va en un <div> donde usa la etiqueta php para recuperar ciertas variables como de sesión, etc, y abajo del todo del archivo hay una etiqueta <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: Mi listado de registros lo lee de un json

Comment: En tus scripts, deberías tener inicializado el modulo de angular, tener en tu tag de body o div principal un atributo ng-app="" y además, tener el ng-controller="" donde le indicas el controlador que usa esa vista del codigo. Tienes en alguna parte de tu codigo algo como angular.module() o ng-app?

Comment: Sí, tengo esto: <div id="sf_admin_container" ng-app="ejemplares" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

Comment: vale, pues tienes que tener un <script> donde dentro tengas algo como ... `angular.controller('MainCtrl', function(){...Lógica del controller....}`. Ahí es donde tienes que poner lo de la parte de Controller.  Y tu codigo HTML tiene que estar dentro del tag de ese div

Comment: ops!, pues no hay nada que tenga un "angular.controller" en ningún archivo de todo el proyecto :(

Comment: Mira el codepen que te he dejado arriba y lo mismo te puede ayudar un poco. Parece que estas intentando utilizar angular pero no estas haciendolo correctamente. Has importado el angular.js?

Comment: Espera, que ya lo he encontrado, pone: app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter)

Comment: Si en realidad, funcionar funciona, porque los filtros funcionan bien, carga el json, todo esto ha sido a raiz de otro problema que justo expuse ayer, un problema con los checkbox y la paginación

Comment: Pues pon ahí dentro el codigo y cambia tus checks por los que te dí y ya me dirás si funciona

Answer (score 0):

Intenta recorrer cada elemento del array y asignar el modelo del `checkbox` a `false`:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.model = {};
  $scope.model.items = [{text:"item1", selected : false }, {text:"item2", selected: 2}, {text:"item3", selected: false}, {text:"item4", selected: false}];
  
  $scope.model.checkAll = false;
  
  $scope.model.checkAllItems = function(item) {
     for(var i = 0; i < $scope.model.items.length;i++)
     {
        $scope.model.items[i].selected = $scope.model.checkAll;
     }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="model.checkAll" ng-change="model.checkAllItems()" /> seleccionar todo
 <ul ng-repeat="item in model.items">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" /> {{item.text}}
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```